# Is there a way to quicken the process of doing carton labels?

Tags: excel

i am doing carton labels on excel where i have to put the company name then the number which increases by 1 each time. for example, if it was Apple Inc., it should be:

```
AI - 001.
AI - 002.
AI - 003.
...
```

i did custom formatting for the cell where all i need to type is the numbers. so the custom format is `\A\I - ###.` and then i used formulas to auto generate the next few numbers, which is already quite fast. but because i need to do this for multiple companies, it would take a long time for me to change the formatting of the cells 1 by 1 to say SECL (Samsung Electronics Co Ltd.). is there a way to do this faster? and it cant be auto filled because the cells are not consecutive, they are a few cells apart. for example, the first cell is `C12` and the next is `C27` and the next is `C42` and the next is `C57` so on and so forth.

Comment: Welcome to SO. *is there a way to do this faster?* Probably with macros, you'll need to code something.  read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

If you start in row 1 with cell A1 with Apple, then just do something like:

```
=A1&" - "&row()
```

Drag down and as you add data in cells A2, A3 then it will complete.

You could add:

```
=IF(A1="","",A1&" - "&row())
```

and drag that down to tidy it up a bit.

Comment: I would have done that the same approach, it is the easiest way to do.

Answer (score 0):

The formula approach is certainly relevant in many situtations.
But for what you are doing it may be easier to use the autofill functionality, so try out a few things:
E.g. In A3 enter 'AI-1001' and in A4 'AI-1002', select the two cells together, and drag down.
If you need many thousands of rows, Goto (F5) say A10000 and enter the number 1.
Copy that (CTRL-c), then F8, then CTRL-up-arrow, and paste (CTRL-v) so you have zeroes in all the cells in between.
Then you don't need to drag down, you can just double-click on the bottom right of the two selected cells at the top.

If at the top you enter AB-1001 and AB-1004, you will get AB-1007, AB-1010 etc
If you enter AC-1001 and AD-1005, you will get AC-1002, AD-1006 etc
If you select three cells with the third one blank you will have to actually drag, rather than double-click, but get a pattern which is sometimes useful.

Comment: You can even select 15 cells of which 14 are blank so you get output every 15 rows. And indeed do multiple columns at the same time. So start with AD-002000 - drag across for nine rows; in the row below do the same starting with AD-002010. Then select the twenty cells together and drag down